# fork() return value is not same as ps command output for the process

Tags: c, linux, process

```
pid = fork();

if (pid == 0)
{
  pid = execve(command, args, envvars);

  if (pid == -1)
  {
    printf("failed to execute: %s\n", command);
  }
}
else if (pid > 0)
{
  if (strcmp(rootcmd, C_EXEC) == 0)
  {
    wait(pid);

    /** Reap any zombie processes that hang around */
    while ((pid = waitpid(-1, (int *)&status, WNOHANG)) > 0)
    {
    }

    pid = 0;
  }
}
printf("%d\n", pid);
```

In the above code, pid value of the child process doesn't match with the pid found in the `ps -ax` command output. In the example I tried, the pid value returned from the `ps -ax` command is 17 and the pid value returned from the fork() is 1701969937. Can someone help me understand, why the values are different?

Comment: Show us the output of `ps` and highlight the line with your process.

Comment: Well, 1701969937 == 0x65720011, notice the bottom half 0x0011 == 17.  Maybe your Linux returns the child pid in the bottom half of the result and some flags in the top half?

Comment: Have you declared `pid_t pid;` ? Also, please cast `(int)pid` in your `printf`. At last, show more code and compile it with `gcc -Wall -g`

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks for giving me a hint. pid is part of structure which also has char array. I figured it out that the char array is overflowing the pid value.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, -ax param means, that you want to show not only your processes, but ALL of them. Maybe, in the table you see UID+PID instead of pid. Use

```
ps -ef | pg
```

instead. What do you see there?

To see every process on the system using standard syntax:

```
ps -e
ps -ef
ps -eF
ps -ely
```

To see every process on the system using BSD syntax:

```
ps ax
ps axu
```

Are you sure you need BSD syntax?